# For the Vue autocomplete search option, how can I take the inputText as an input if the inputText is not found in the autocomplete fields?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a form that includes a dropdown that includes 2 items as of now. With the autocomplete code, I can search for either option by typing in the inputBox. 
However, if the user types in something that is not present -- "no data available" is displayed. If this happens, I want to instead take what the user inputted as a new item to be added to my list.

Is there any way to do that? Currently if I click outside the inputBox, my search term disappears as well.

````
<v-flex xs7>
                            <v-autocomplete solo
                                            v-model="customTemplateType"
                                            :items="templateTypes"
                                            :item-value="templateTypes"
                                            class="f-small f-select-ash f-no-validation-input">
                            </v-autocomplete>
                        </v-flex>
```
````

Comment: use a `v-combobox` instead.

Comment: Thanks! Looks like that will do it